# How to hide an iframe after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I got a stuck in this piece of code

The full code

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function hide(kaka){
            var temp=document.getElementById(kaka).visibility;

            temp=(temp=='visible')?'hidden':'visible';
        }

        function remove(kaka){
            var temp=document.getElementById(kaka).display;

            temp=(temp=='block')?'none':'block';
        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>

<IFRAME id="kaka" SRC="ads.php" WIDTH=10000 HEIGHT=10000></IFRAME>
<script> 
</body>
```

I'm trying to make the `iframe` to hide after someone's click

Answer (score 0):

`visibility` and `display` are just text strings, so setting them to a variable, and then changing the variable, won't change the element.

```
function toggle(kaka) {
    var temp=document.getElementById(kaka).visibility;
    temp=(temp=='visible')?'hidden':'visible';
    document.getElementById(kaka).visibility=temp;
}
```